# Limit the number of ID numbers on a single line with a regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a single line of text in Notepad++ containing over 250 ID numbers separated by spaces. I want to separate them to only allow a maximum of 25 ID numbers per line.

How can I limit the number of ID numbers on each line using Notepad++'s regex search & replace tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Replace` to select a certain number of ID numbers in a capturing group and then add a new line after them, e.g.:

```
Find what:     ((\d+\s*){25})
Replace with:  \1\n
```

Make sure `Regular expression` is set as search mode and just do `Replace all`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I was even able to substitute `\s` with any arbitrary separator character.